# Replace String in Scala

Tags: scala, quotes

I have variable like this:

```
val data = "'1','a','13','100','b'"
```

and I want to replace the variable became to

```
val data = "1,'a',13,100,'b'"
```

If variable has a integer character, its will be remove the quotes (`''`). How can I do it?

Comment: Where is the List in this code?

Comment: if I have list like this.
val list = List(1,13,100) -> this is a list of integer..

and then can I replace val data based on list value above?

Comment: I don't know how it relates to this question. Where did the strings go? Scala is a strictly typed language, you can not have both strings and integers in the same list. Do you want to remove the strings from the list? Can you update your question with a proper input/output example?

Comment: I want to remove the quotes if the value is in list - > val list = List(1,13,100)

from val data = "'1','a','13','100','b'"  to val data = "1,'a',13,100,'b'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you want?

```
val data = "'1','a','13','100','b'"  //a String, not a List
val newData = "'(\\d+)'".r.replaceAllIn(data, "$1")
//newData: String = 1,'a',13,100,'b'
```